# Testing Roaming App Data in Emulator C#

Tags: c#, uwp

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and trying to program a C# UWP application for Windows phone. When I try to test roaming app data between the host computer and the emulator (Mobile emulator 10.0.15063.0) the data does not sync.  Even after waiting several hours.  The emulator appears to be working as my emails and calendar sync across devices. When I search for the files on the host computer it appears to be created correctly:

```
C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Packages\23840StartPoint.StartPointRunning_x6wjmepvaasdr\RoamingState
```

I have checked the package manifest and the package name and version match. I have tried several different options but nothing works.  Am I missing something.

The Application Data sample from GitHub is what I used as a model teaching myself to write/read files. It does not work on my setup either.

```
var applicationData = ApplicationData.Current;

ulong storage = applicationData.RoamingStorageQuota;

//Create file client.txt => store data => Roaming folder
ApplicationDataContainer roamingSettings =   ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings;

StorageFolder roamingFolder1 = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;
StorageFile file1 = await roamingFolder1.CreateFileAsync(Filename1, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

SetUpFlag = "true";
String string6 = Views.Colors101.m_BackGroundColor + ";" +  Views.Colors101.m_CalendarColor + ";" + Views.Colors101.m_HeaderColor;

String toWrite = SetUpFlag + ";" + string6;

StorageFile xfile1 = await roamingFolder1.GetFileAsync(Filename1);

await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(xfile1, toWrite);

ApplicationData.Current.SignalDataChanged();
```

Comment: How do you share the data, between pc and uwp??

Comment: I am sharing a small text file (approx. 150 bytes) via a roaming folder. I am new and uncertain how to add code into my comment.  Can you suggest a method.  I tried adding back-ticks but did not work.

Comment: You can edit your original question to add relative code snippet and other updates.

Comment: And could you please test the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ApplicationData) on your devices? If you have conditions, could you please test your project on the computer and another phone device?

Comment: Great, I will definitely try this.  The Application Data sample from GitHub is what I used as a model teaching myself to write/read files. It does not work in my setup either.  Please refer to code added into my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try my version to see if it works better..

```
const string _listofStuffFile = "allMyStuff.txt";
public static async Task<bool> SaveMyListData(List<string> saveData)
    {
        try
        {
            var savedStuffFile = await ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder.CreateFileAsync(_listofStuffFile, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            using (Stream ws = await savedStuffFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
            {
                var ss = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<string>));
                ss.WriteObject(ws, saveData);
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch { }
        return false;
    }

public static async Task<List<string>> GetMyListData()
    {
        try
        {
            var rs = await ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(_listofStuffFile);
            if (rs == null)
                return new List<string>();
            var ss = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<string>));
            var sr = (List<string>)ss.ReadObject(rs);
            return sr;
        }
        catch { }
        return new List<string>();
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate your efforts @ArchAngel. Unfortunately, your solution did not work either. I read that while in debugging mode apps will not suspend.  Is it possible that I need to do something to force a suspend and do I need to do something special to release file handles on suspend.